# как я могу сделать прямоугольник фоном для кнопок и текста?

Tags: html

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>EPIC GLITCH WEBSITE</title>
    <style>
        body {
            background: #F2F2F2;
            max-width: 900px;
            margin: 10px auto;
            padding: 30px;
        }
        //body {
          //    background: #c7b39b url(wallpaper.jpg); //фон из картинки
          //   }
        h1{
            color: #4C4C4C;
            padding-bottom: 20px;
            margin-bottom: 20px;
            border-bottom: 2px solid #BEBEBE;
        }
        p{
            font:italic;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Это тестовый сайт</h1>
<p><a href="wat.html">Что это?</a></p>
<p><a href="who.html">Кто сделал?</a></p>
<p><a href="when.html">Когда?</a></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ну начнём с того что изначально почти любой html элемент прямоугольный, соответственно простая замена фона(css background) сделает ровно то что спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0):

Советую обратиться к ресурсу http://htmlbook.ru/, там все подробно написано что и для чего использовать

```html
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>EPIC GLITCH WEBSITE</title>
    <style>
        body {
            background: #F2F2F2;
            max-width: 900px;
            margin: 10px auto;
            padding: 30px;
        }
        //body {
          //    background: #c7b39b url(wallpaper.jpg); //фон из картинки
          //   }
        h1{
            color: #4C4C4C;
            padding-bottom: 20px;
            margin-bottom: 20px;
            border-bottom: 2px solid #BEBEBE;
        }
        p{
            font:italic;
          
        }
        .kvadrat
        {
         background:  #ccc;
         width: 150px; 
         padding: 5px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Это тестовый сайт</h1>
<div class="kvadrat">
<a href="wat.html">Что это?</a> </div>
<p><a href="who.html">Кто сделал?</a></p>
<p><a href="when.html">Когда?</a></p>

</body>
</html>
```